# How to dissolve candle wax (paraffin)?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, solubility, fats

Wikipedia states that waxes can be dissolved by non-polar organic solvents.

I failed to dissolve candle wax in both acetone and ethanol, which are the only organic solvents I have at home.

I have some clothes with wax stuck on them. How can I dissolve the wax and drive it away without damaging my clothing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ethanol and acetone are not non-polar organic solvents. Each one has  a slight dipole moment; due to the difference of electronegativity between $\ce{H}$ and  $\ce{O}$ in ethanol and between $\ce{C}$ and  $\ce{O}$ in acetone.  Wax is composed of heavy, long-chain alkanes. And as "Like dissolves like" try to dissolve your wax in toluene or in xylene.

Comment: A proven way to get rid of candle wax in clothes is putting several sheets of newspaper on top and then apply a warm iron.

Comment: You can also put the clothes in the freezer and a substantial portion of he wax will crack off.

Answer (score 17):

Being a chemist, I know that paraffin would require a lipophilic solvent as pointed out by others. It occurred to me that ordinary vegetable oil is a cheap and of course innocuous lipophilic substance. I spilled about 2 oz molten candle wax on a marble surface and after it solidified removed a good portion by scraping with a plastic spoon. This was followed by adding about a tablespoon of vegetable oil and mixing with the spoon. The wax dissolved in the oil with no problem and could be mopped up with a paper towel. Treatment of the oily residue with sink soap removed what was left. Hope this helps.

Comment: Gonna try that right now!

Comment: Just wanted to update - candle wax did not dissolve in sunflower vegetable oil.

Comment: Wow, this works great! This needs to be common household knowledge...

Comment: It’s a great tip! Now it doesn’t dissolve readily and requires some elbow grease but a health dose of canola oil, a cloth and some rubbing and it came off in a few minutes. Perfect for hardwood floors as I don’t have to worry about harsh chemicals on the finish.

Comment: Great answer!! Canola oil and rubbing with my thumbnail took the candle wax out of my tablecloth. Then I hit it with spray’n wash and put it in the washing machine to take the oil out.

Answer (score 4):

A readily available mixture of various non-polar alkanes  would be petrol (gasoline).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_spirit

Comment: However, I don't think this will result in clean clothes. You will clean the wax, but it will then stink of petrol.

Answer (score 1):

Ordinary candle wax is readily removed by Methylated Spirits, especially if is on a candle stick. Scrape the bulk off carefully and then use a soft cloth with meths.

Answer (score 1):

Dry clean your clothes. The solvents used in dry cleaning work well.

I had the airline industry pump my suitcase and suits full of jet fuel. Even with professional cleaning they still stunk. All had to be replaced.